# How to let Mirage passthrough node modules access?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I am using SimpleMDE which seems send a request to `/node_modules/typo-js/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic` internally.

[image]

[image]

How to pass this GET request using Mirage?

I am using the following setting with no effect.

```
  this.passthrough('node_modules/**');
  this.passthrough('node_modules/typo-js/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic');

  this.passthrough('/node_modules/**');
  this.passthrough('/node_modules/typo-js/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic');
```

Code inside mirage config file,

```
export default function() {
  this.urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:3000';
  this.namespace = '';
  this.timing = 400;

  /*
    Shorthand cheatsheet:

    this.get('/posts');
    this.post('/posts');
    this.get('/posts/:id');
    this.put('/posts/:id'); // or this.patch
    this.del('/posts/:id');

    http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/shorthands/
  */

  this.passthrough('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/**');
  this.passthrough('/node_modules/typo-js/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic');
  this.passthrough('/node_modules/typo-js/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic')
  this.passthrough();
}
```

Comment: try `this.passthrough('/node_modules/**');` note `/` in beginning

Comment: I have tried both the results are the same

Comment: Just try  `this.passthrough()`

Comment: It is not in the same domain so it won't work and I do not know why

Comment: Is this valid ajax request ? I am guessing something weird is happening in typo-js bundling. If possible, Could you please check after disabling ember-cli mirage

Comment: It's working fine without mirage and although there is warning the lib still functioning